# Create a json file with both static data and a dynamic list of IP's

Tags: java, json, file, programmatically-created

I am new to creating files. I need to create JSON that I will import into my firewall. I created two test rules so that I could export the format of the file I will need to create for import. The final output will need to look like this:

```
[
    {
        "id" : 1,
        "enabled" : true,
        "category" : null,
        "readOnly" : null,
        "description" : "Test Rule #1",
        "string" : "1.2.3.4",
        "name" : null,
        "flagged" : true,
        "javaClass" : "com.testServer.uvm.node.GenericRule",
        "blocked" : true
    }, {
        "id" : 2,
        "enabled" : true,
        "category" : null,
        "readOnly" : null,
        "description" : "Test Rule #2",
        "string" : "1.2.3.5",
        "name" : null,
        "flagged" : true,
        "javaClass" : "com.testServer.uvm.node.GenericRule",
        "blocked" : true
    }
]
```

I have a text file that contains all of the IP's I want insert into the file. The Description will be a static description.

The text file IP's are listed one per line like:

```
1.2.3.4  
1.2.3.5
```

I'm pretty new at programming I've used Java and VB before but have never had to read a file, insert that record into a new string in a new file, and then do the next record. If another language would be easier I will learn whatever I need to. This is something that I will be using for other projects after I get the hang of it.

Comment: You may be here asking this question too soon as you have not shown us your own attempt to solve this nor described what problems you may be having with this attempt.

Comment: Have you looked into prior similar questions yet and tried to implement their solutions? That's the first thing that I would do were I in your shoes.

Answer (score 1):

Give it a try it will work, It uses JSONSimple library to prepare the JSON Data

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // file name from where you read the urls
    List<String> url = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("url.txt"));
    //List to hold the contents and prepare json data
    JSONArray list = new JSONArray();

    try {

        FileWriter file = new FileWriter("test.json");

        for (int i = 0; i < url.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
            obj.put("id", i+ 1);
            obj.put("enabled", new Boolean(true));
            obj.put("category", null);
            obj.put("readOnly", null);
            obj.put("description", new String("Test Rule #" + (i + 1)));
            obj.put("string", url.get(i));
            obj.put("name", null);
            obj.put("flagged", new Boolean(true));
            obj.put("javaClass", new String("com.testServer.uvm.node.GenericRule"));
            obj.put("blocked", new Boolean(true));
            list.add(obj);
        }
        file.write(list.toJSONString());
        file.flush();
        file.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```